Firebase Google login in Web shows incorrect App name
Problem: I set the App name in the Google Cloud console but it doesn't appear in my web google login popup window, instead of xxx.firebaseapp.com.
As image showed, Google login popup window doesn't show correct app name which sets in the OAuth content screen in the Google Cloud console.

The configuration in the Google Cloud console is like below:

What I want is like the image below:


Please set your browser to English

@LindaLawton-DaImTo updated

a) If you are using FedCM GIS APIs, this is expected. See https://developers.googleblog.com/en/announcing-federated-credential-management-fedcm-beta-for-google-identity-services/
b) If you're using standard OIDC, then you need your app to go through OAuth app verification before the app name will be displayed. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/brand-verification

My Android and iOS app shows the correct app name, only PC web is incorrect
